# How to update the dependency of one package which is in package-lock.json

Tags: npm, lodash, npm-install

We want to update the lodash version to 4.17.11 but it is dependency of grunt-angular-translate . grunt-angular-translate is in package.json . If i am updating the grunt-angular-translate to 0.3.0 it is not updating the lodash to version 4.7.11 .How can we update the dependency which is in package-lock.json.

package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^1.0.3",
    "grunt-angular-translate": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-bump": "^0.8.0",
```

package-lock.json:

```
"grunt-angular-translate": {
      "version": "0.3.0",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/grunt-angular-translate/-/grunt-angular-translate-0.3.0.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-vQEYr6JNj1cCMf2NUtgp2AjFEbM=",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "flat": "^1.2.0",
        "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.0",
        "lodash": "~2.4.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "lodash": {
          "version": "2.4.2",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/lodash/-/lodash-2.4.2.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha1-+t2DS5aDBz2hebPq5tnA0VBT9z4=",
          "dev": true
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [npm docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json):

> **package-lock.json** is automatically generated for any operations where
>   npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It
>   describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent
>   installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of
>   intermediate dependency updates.
>
> This file is intended to be committed into source repositories, and
>   serves various purposes:
>
> Describe a single representation of a dependency tree such that
>   teammates, deployments, and continuous integration are guaranteed to
>   install exactly the same dependencies.
>
> Provide a facility for users to “time-travel” to previous states of
>   node_modules without having to commit the directory itself.
>
> To facilitate greater visibility of tree changes through readable
>   source control diffs.
>
> And optimize the installation process by allowing npm to skip repeated
>   metadata resolutions for previously-installed packages.

In `package.json` you specify which npm packages you are utilizing in your app. In other words on which you have a specific dependency so your package can function.

`package-lock.json` is a big "map" of each of the packages **your app uses** and **their dependencies** which you can not impact.

In your case `grunt-angular-translate` has **its own dependency** on `"lodash": "~2.4.1"` and you can not change it and should not try to since that package is supposed to work with that version and not with 2 versions higher package where there may be a bunch of breaking changes.

You can upgrade your direct dependency of lodash to its latest version but that would not update `grunt-angular-translate` dependency to lodash to that version and it really should not.

What should really happen is in your `node_modules` folder you will get your updated lodash (and you can check by looking at its package.json and the version inside). In that same folder if you go into the `grunt-angular-translate` folder and look at its own `node_modules` ... it should have its own lodash folder with lodash `2.4.1` in it.

Comment: Because of this package-lock.json i am getting Prototype Pollution Vulnerability for lodash:2.4.1 . If i stop generating package-lock.json with `npm config set package-lock false` is there any chance of not getting this vulnerability again? Thanks.

Comment: You are getting yourself in other problems if you avoid all together `package-lock`. Either loose that dependency or open an issue on their repo and ask for it to be updated due to this vulnerability. If that repo is no longer supported that is yet another reason to replace it all together.

Comment: Is there any other way to get rid of this vulnerability ?

Comment: Well this PR (https://github.com/angular-translate/grunt-angular-translate/pull/93/files) is doing exactly what you want so you can either ask (thumbs up etc) on that PR or simply fork that repo and update those packages yourself. At this point it seems that lib is no longer actively maintained so you really have nothing to worry about in terms or missing on new updates :| etc.

Comment: this didn't answer the question. Lets say I use "superagent" at "3.8.3" in my project and I want to update my package-lock to be "5.1.0". Do I have to manually adapt it or is there a way that npm can handle this targeted updates on lock files?